# How to Check if a Page Exists by URL?

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages, urls, hierarchical

I need to display certain content depending on whether or not a page URL exists.  I don't want to check by title, because certain pages will have the same title, and just different parent pages.

**For example one page may be:**

1. `http://example.com/analysis/firstNamelastName`
2. `http://example.com/exercise/firstNamelastName`

I just need to know if one of these URL exists or not.

Comment: analysis and exercise are categories? I'm not sure your approach is the best and I'm trying to understand what you want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make a list of paths to check...

```
$page_paths = array(
    'analysis/firstNamelastName',
    'exercise/firstNamelastName'
);
```

Then check if there's a page object for each of the page paths.

```
foreach( $page_paths as $page_path ) {

    echo '<code>' . $page_path . '</code> ' . PHP_EOL;

    if( ! $page = get_page_by_path( $page_path ) ){
        echo 'Does not exist.' . PHP_EOL;
    } else{
        echo 'Exists and resolves to: <code>' . get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '</code>' . PHP_EOL;
    }  

}
```

You can actually use [`get_page_by_path();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) for Post Types other than `page`. See the third parameter.

Comment: Is there something like this but for multisite?